# Is it better to install 32bit Ubuntu for a EMT64 processor?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, dell, 32-bit

I got a Dell OptiPlex 9010 recently - it has an Intel® Core™ i7-3770 Processor. 
Intel declares in the specifications (http://ark.intel.com/products/65719/) that it's compatible with 64bit instruction set. 
But my BIOS tells me its EMT64 and not a true 64 bit processor.

So, which would be a better choice - 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu for this ?
(I need to make best possible use of my 16 GB RAM, majorly for running monte carlo simulations for physics.)

Answer (score 0):

The consideration is also whether there is a program that is not easily available also for 64-bit architecture (there are some, but not many these days).

However, if you've got 16GB RAM, I would definitely suggest giving the 64-bit version a try. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

intel says it is 64-Bit architectrure compatible:

http://ark.intel.com/m/products/65719/Intel-Core-i7-3770-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz?wapkw=i7+3770

Using 32 bit would "waste" about 12GB RAM